# How to build a composite Rack application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, rack

I am trying to build an application that uses Sinatra for rendering the views, and handles file uploads, while using another library for handling web socket communication (em-websocket). Normally, em-websocket is an EvenMachine library that runs on a different port, but there is a "Rack compatible" version that somehow wraps this library. I would like to combine these in order to create a new application that can be easily added/integrated/mounted to an existing Rails application or used as a standalone application. I have not done this sort of thing before so I don't know where to start and how to do this. How can I create this sort of composite Rack application that doesn't require any extra ports and is easily mountable?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look [here](http://codex.heroku.com/past/2011/2/15/sinatrabase_in_the_modulnd/) about creating modular Sinatra applications and combining them in a larger Sinatra application.  You could look into mounting [Cramp](http://cramp.in/) inside of a main Sinatra application.